# How to only show one spinner after a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

What I am trying to do is if a user selects one radio button, a specific spinner is shown next to the radio button, all spinners are hidden on load up and only the one corrisponding to the radio button should be shown when that radio button is selected, currently I got the spinners to hide, but I can only get either all or none of the spinners to show up, how can I restrict this?

This is my current code:

```
            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.labelMarkRange}" for="range"  />
            <p:panelGrid columns="3">
                <p:selectOneRadio id="range" value="{formBean.number}" layout="grid" columns="1" required = "True"
                                  requiredMessage="#{bundle.messageSelectMarkRange}" > 
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 - 19" itemValue="1" /> 
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="20 - 39" itemValue="2" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="40 - 49" itemValue="4" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="50 - 59" itemValue="5" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="60 - 69" itemValue="6" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="70 - 79" itemValue="7" />  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="80 - 100" itemValue="8" />  
                </p:selectOneRadio>  


                <p:outputPanel>  
                    <!-- look into validation for this to prevent any unwanted values, better than the min max etc -->
                    <p>
                        <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner0-19" value="#{spinnerController.number1}" 
                                   stepFactor = "1"  min="0" max="19" rendered="#{facesContext.postback}">  
                            <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                        </p:spinner> 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner20-39" value="#{spinnerController.number1}" 
                                   stepFactor = "1"  min="20" max="39" rendered="#{facesContext.postback}">  
                            <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                        </p:spinner> 
                    </p>
```

So for example if a user selected the 0 - 19 spinner then only ajax spinner 0-19 should be displayed

How can I do this ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have ajax call whenever you select a radio button like this

```
 <p:selectOneRadio id="range" value="#{formBean.number}" layout="grid" columns="1"   required = "True"
                              requiredMessage="#{bundle.messageSelectMarkRange}" > 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 - 19" itemValue="1" /> 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="20 - 39" itemValue="2" />  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="40 - 49" itemValue="4" />  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="50 - 59" itemValue="5" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="60 - 69" itemValue="6" />  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="70 - 79" itemValue="7" />  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="80 - 100" itemValue="8" />  

    <p:ajax process="@this" update="mySpinnerPanel" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>  

<p:outputPanel>  
                <!-- look into validation for this to prevent any unwanted values, better than the min max etc -->
                <p>
            <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner0-19" value="#{spinnerController.number1}" 
             stepFactor = "1"  min="0" max="19" rendered="#{formBean.number eq 1}">  
                        <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />  
                    </p:spinner> 
                </p>  
    <p:outputPanel>
```

Similarly you can do other spinners in your panel. I gave Id your output panel as mySpinnerPanel change it to as you wish and # is missing in value attribute of radio button.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks i have tried that, but it never displays the spinner after a the radio button is selected

Comment: I presumed that your number variable in formbean is an integer. If it is String then can you try with the condition #{formBean.number eq '1'}. And just put an alert of that eq condition to check whether you are getting false or true

Comment: And try changing update="range,mySpinnerPanel" in p:ajax call.

Comment: Currently i am not using the formbean value at all, i commented it out as i did not need this to pass a value to the backing bean at all, if i was to enable that would it be better ?

Comment: I am not aware of rendered="#{facesContext.postback}". So I tried to suggest a way to do with a known variable which you binded as a value of selected radio. So I feel it is better to use and try those two suggestions in the above comment. update of radio should be mandatory on ajax call to get latest selection.

Comment: Edit, managed to get it working after re reading what you siad, thansk a lot for the help :)